# What are some good resources to learn about audio manipulation/engineering/programming?

Tags: audio

what are some good resources to learn about audio manipulation/engineering/programming?

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in writing audio effects, these two sites are excellent:

- [Music DSP](http://www.musicdsp.org/)
- [KVR Developer Forum](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33)

Answer (score 2):

There are many open source projects like STK, CLAM, SuperCollider and so forth, which provide examples of C++ audio synthesis in their source.  Looking at these projects may be helpful, but they are intended for use without needing to know about the underlying algorithms.  So to start, I can only think to recommend books:

- Perry Cook's Real Sound Synthesis goes over the synthesis in physical modeling of instruments and objects.
- DAFX (Digtal Audio Effects) is a book which is a collection of articles that go over many basic audio effects algorithms (e.g. compressor, noise gate, reverb,) with examples in c.
- Richard Moore's The Elements of Computer Music goes over audio dsp basics and a different breed of effects used in academic computer music (e.g. time stretching, analysis-resynthesis, FM.)  I found it easier to read (since it is targeted at musicians,) but it still goes as far to include c explanations of important algorithms such as the FFT.

I would be interested to hear of some online tutorials/guides for DSP, as I think it is more open than recommending books.  Its nice to learn about the Music DSP site from Mark's post, but it seems more advanced as I didn't see something like a guide/tutorial to cover the necessary basics.

Answer (score 1):

http://electro-music.com/forum/ is a forum where stuff like this is discussed from time to time. Check out some of the forums under DIY. They've just started a wiki with articles like this one:

http://electro-music.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Articles.Convolution

Answer (score 1):

The [Audio Programming Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262014467) was a pretty awesome read/reference! Although there are some typos, etc., it is really extensive and has tons of examples. C & C++.

Answer (score 1):

I found this website before taking an online course about Digital Signal Processing:

[SEEING CIRCLES, SINES, AND SIGNALS](https://jackschaedler.github.io/circles-sines-signals/)

> "A COMPACT PRIMER ON DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSING"

The topic is really well presented and explained, a **great primer**!